# Serving static files with Jersey - Error while closing the output stream in order to commit response

Tags: java, jax-ws, jersey-2.0, static-files

I'm trying to implement a project that will basically serve static files that are located in a folder of the project. I'm using Jersey 2.22.1. It should be a method that receives a filename and answers with the requested file.

Implementation:

```
@GET
@Path("/{filename : .*}")
public Response getFile(@PathParam("filename") String filename) {

    String f = getFileFromSomewhere(filename);

    StreamingOutput fileStream =  new StreamingOutput()
    {
        @Override
        public void write(java.io.OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
        {
            try
            {
                java.nio.file.Path path = Paths.get(f);
                byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
                output.write(data);
                output.flush();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new WebApplicationException("File Not Found !!");
            }
        }
    };

    return Response
            .ok(fileStream)
            .build();
}
```

The following error occurs:

```
GRAVE: Error while closing the output stream in order to commit response.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getOutputStream(Response.java:628)
```

The files are being requested by a browser and i have noticed that the error only occurs with .js files (it's ok with.html and .css files). There are reasons why this files should be served by this method and not by the conventional mode.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Just curious, but why don't you just let the servlet container default servlet serve them. There's more than just "serving" of the file you need to take care of, for instance caching.

Comment: Maybe I could do what I want in a easier way... I'm trying to do something like the WebServlet class in H2 database does but using Jax ws (https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/master/h2/src/main/org/h2/server/web/WebServlet.java). In H2 database case, they have a servlet that handle requests to files of H2 Console, so we can set it in the web.xml of any webapp and the h2 console will be available. I'd like to do the same but for another proposal. The project will be used as a jar library like in h2. Would you have any suggestions on how to do this with Jax or another easier way?

Comment: I used your code to see what is happening and it worked perfectly. Do you have any particular type of file for which you are facing the issue . I tried with JPEG , XML and text all worked .